# Apps Script - Format data in one column into seperate rows

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script that changes the format of data in table A into a the format of table B.

**Table A**

| Name | Math Score | Reading Score | Science Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karl | 25 | 35 | 29 |

**Table B**

| Name | Math Score | Reading Score | Science Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karl | 25 |  |  |
| Karl |  | 35 |  |
| Karl |  |  | 29 |

Ideally I'd like to use Apps Script functions or google sheet functions but I was unable to figure out something. I am open to trying answers using loops but I am afraid it will very very slow on my larger data set.

Answer (score 0):

check out this script maybe it will help if you need editing feel free to write

```
function expandData() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = dataRange.getValues();

var expandedData = [];

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
var name = data[i][0];
var mathScore = data[i][1];
var readingScore = data[i][2];
var scienceScore = data[i][3];

expandedData.push([name, mathScore, "", ""]);
expandedData.push([name, "", readingScore, ""]);
expandedData.push([name, "", "", scienceScore]);
}

sheet.getRange(data.length + 0, 6, expandedData.length, 4).setValues(expandedData);
}
```

[image]